# Pandas Dataframe to pivot table - Make new column based off the addition of the previous two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a pandas dataframe where the columns are dates rounded up by month. There are two columns in each month, one column is the quantity expected and the other column is the actual quantity. The rows are all product items. It’s basically forecast data, if you work in supply chain you know what I mean.

What I want to be able to do is for every month column, subtract the actual quantity from the expected from the previous month column, then add the current months column expected to it for the total of the current month expected and put that value in a new column for that month.
I want to be able to do this for all the months in the dataframe.

If I didn’t explain it well basically I have what I am expecting to get in for a product for a month and I have a sold amount for that month. I want to subtract them from each other and have it carry over to the next month ( and for every month after that ) to see if I am positive or negative for that item in any given month.

Is this possible?

EDIT: adding more information to use:

```py
data = np.array([['2020-08-01',"10", "5", "item1", 'AF'],
                ['2020-08-01', "2", "4", "item1", "QF"],
                ['2020-09-01', "15", "30", "item1", "AF"],
                ['2020-09-01', "10", "5", "item1", "QF"]])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['Month', 'ExpectedQty', 'ActualQty', 'ProductID', 'Warehouse'])

pivot_table = df.pivot_table(columns=df.Month,
                            values=['ActualQty', 'ExpectedQty'],
                            index=[df['ProductID'], df['Warehouse']],
                            fill_value='')
pivot_table.columns = pivot_table.columns.swaplevel(0, 1)
pivot_table.sort_index(axis=1, level=0, inplace=True)
```

How to turn "pivot_table" from the code above into the look desired below?

```
          Date       |           2020-08-01        |          2020-09-01           |
          Quantities | Expected | Actual | New Col | Expected | Actual |  New Col  |
                             
ProductID | Warehouse 
item1     |   AF     |      10  |    5   |    -5   |    15    |   30   |     10    |
              QF     |      2   |    4   |     2   |    10    |    5   |     -3    |
item2 ...
```

Comment: please add some sample data and desired output

Comment: I will do so this evening. I’m out for the day at the moment.

Comment: Your question won't be answered until then :(

Comment: Added in the data and desired output. If there is a better way to do this let me know, I don't use StackOverflow a lot. @ZLi and

Comment: @GenericName it is better to put them as code instead of screenshots, such as `data=pd.DataFrame...`

Comment: @ZLi I have added example data

Comment: @richardec I've added in data and desired output :-)

Comment: What is "New Col"?

Comment: @richardec "New Col" is the new column I would like the `(Actual` - Expected)` to equal and then carry over to the next month. I want the resulting amounts for each month to carry over to the next so I can see how I need to adjust my purchases and arrival dates of the products. So each month should look like `((Actual + New Col from the previous month)` - Expected) = New Col of the current month`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# your code for data with three months
data = np.array([['2020-08-01',"10", "5", "item1", 'AF'],
                ['2020-08-01', "2", "4", "item1", "QF"],
                ['2020-09-01', "15", "30", "item1", "AF"],
                ['2020-09-01', "10", "5", "item1", "QF"],
                ['2020-10-01', "10", "5", "item1", "AF"],
                ['2020-10-01', "10", "5", "item1", "QF"]])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['Month', 'ExpectedQty', 'ActualQty', 'ProductID', 'Warehouse'])
df[['ExpectedQty', 'ActualQty']] = df[['ExpectedQty', 'ActualQty']].astype('float')

# calculate new col
df = df.sort_values('Month')
df['QtyDiff'] = df['ActualQty'] - df['ExpectedQty']
df['QtyDiff_cumsum'] = df.groupby(['ProductID', 'Warehouse'])['QtyDiff'].cumsum()
df['New Col'] = df['QtyDiff_cumsum']
# get pivot table
pivot_table = df.pivot_table(columns='Month',
                             values=['ActualQty', 'ExpectedQty', 'New Col'],
                             index=['ProductID', 'Warehouse'],
                             fill_value='')
pivot_table.columns = pivot_table.columns.swaplevel(0, 1)
pivot_table.sort_index(axis=1, level=0, inplace=True)
pivot_table
```

output: The output is too long so I put an image here:

[image]

Comment: Awesome! This works and does what I asked. Thank you for spending the time and showing me how to do this. :-)

Comment: Hey Z Li, I just applied the code you gave and it works for the example data I provided but in my summary I said I want to be able to continue adding the "new col" to every month. I only put 2 months in the example data and did not put every month in as that would be very long. That being said your code only works for 2 columns and reset every other column. How can the "new col" data persist through every month? The number of months is dynamic.

Comment: Hi @GenericName, yes you are right. In this case it is actually easier. Please see the updated answer. It should work for arbitrary number of months.

Comment: Wow... it's that simple? Man, I whacked my head so long trying to figure out how to do this elegantly with pandas and I gave up and ended up doing it in an ugly brute force way with a for-loop because I didn't think you would come back to update your answer. Haha and all it was, was a one-word function... I have so much to learn about pandas. Thanks for updating your answer, it is very helpful.